# How can I emulate the effects of "Guest Mode" on windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I noticed guest mode (not guest account) has been removed in windows 8, is there anyway I can replicate it's effects of removing any and all user changes on log out?
Furthermore I would like to change the programs that start up when the logs in, and the only way I can see to do this is in the task manager for all users.

Comment: Relevant: http://winsupersite.com/windows-7/windows-7-feature-focus-guest-mode and http://lifehacker.com/5176876/windows-7-guest-mode-creates-bomb+proof-accounts

Comment: From what I read in some snippets guest mode was a somewhat experimental Windows 7 feature, that didn't make it through the final build. Probably they discontinued it in Windows 8, but as I'm unfamiliar with those systems I can't source this statement.

Comment: Those are for windows 7, I mentioned in the post it wasn't available in windows 8.